# How to create list inside a template form in PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I got stuck with PDFBox, trying to integrate a table/list in my acroform.

What I have:
I have a PDF-Template with form fields, which I fill with PDFBox in a JSF application. I must have these templates, because users can upload custom templates (they only have to insert form fields with defined names, that the application will fill).

Now I have the problem, that I want to be able to print a list on a defined form field. This template starts e.g. with a header with logo etc. Then in the middle it has a kind of placeholder where the list/table will be printed. After this a kind of footer (e.g. with signature, ...) will be included. All the content after the list/table must move downwoards, to avoid the table be written over the footer content.

My Questions:

- (How) Can this be done with PDFBox?
- Can the content under the list be moved downwoards, when the table becomes longer?

Comment: I removed your item "If PDFBox is not able to do this, do you know a free software, which is able to do this?" as this effectively is a request for a software recommendation which meanwhile has become off-topic on stack overflow (there is a dedicated software recommendations site for that among the stack exchange sites).

Comment: That been said, filling AcroForm forms is possible with PDFBox, but AcroForms are by definition static in their layout, i.e. there are no growing tables in AcroForms. Nonetheless, to a certain degree one can re-position AcroForm fields. Unfortunately your description of the nature of the templates is too vague, in particular is everything in these templates drawn as form fields (or other annotations) or is there static content, too? If there is static content, too, in particular if it can be arbitrary, moving it is beyond the scope of a stack overflow answer.